# Asymptotic Properties of Functions in Complexity Analysis

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, landau-notation

When dealing with the analysis of time and space complexity of algorithms, is it safe to assume that any function which has tight bounds ( i.e. $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$ is asymptotically positive and asymptotically monotonically increasing.  I mean that for all $n$ greater than or equal to some $n_0$ both those properties hold?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is safe to assume that $f$ is everywhere positive, hence, asymptotically positive. You can't use negative time or space.

It is not safe to assume that $f$ is asymptotically monotonically increasing, since this excludes constant functions, i.e., those which are $\Theta(1)$.

It isn't even safe to assume that $f$ is asymptotically monotonically non-decreasing; this precludes functions that oscillate. A good question might be "do any useful algorithms have asymptotically oscillating time or space complexities," but certainly you could create an algorithm that did.

I suppose a more rigorous answer would ask what your definition of "asymptotically monotonically increasing" means. If it means that it's $\Theta(g(n))$ where $g(n)$ is monotonically increasing for positive $n$, then the answer would be yes, by definition.

Comment: In Cormen it says: "A function f(n) is monotonically increasing if $m \leq n$ implies $f(m)\leq f(n)$".  Wouldn't this allow constant functions?  What you're describing sounds like what Cormen calls "strictly increasing".

Comment: Are there real algorithms whose worst case run time behave like $\sin^2 n + 1$?  I.e. are asymptotically positive, oscillate and have tight upper and lower bounds?

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes Two things: (1) If that's how Cormen defines "monotonically increasing", then Cormen is using a non-standard definition. What Cormen calls "monotonically increasing" most mathematicians (as far as I'm aware) would refer to as "monotonically non-decreasing". Monotonically increasing would be: $m < n$ implies $f(m) < f(n)$. (2) There aren't any algorithms with *that* runtime, but that's just because that function only assumes an integer value for $n = 0$; this can be easily resolved, however. Such a function would be $\Theta(1)$, since it's bounded below by $1$ and above by $2$.

Answer (score 4):

No. There are complexity functions that oscillate, for example [runtime of Mergesort](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/how-to-describe-algorithms-prove-and-analyse-them/2390#2390).

It is not even true that every meaningful complexity function is in $\Theta$ of a monotonically increasing function; see [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10354/common-algorithms-without-asymptotically-tight-bounds/10355#10355) to your older question.

Comment: So the worst case run time of Mergesort oscillates within $n \lg n$ upper and lower bounds?

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes Yes. (To be precise, $\Theta(n \log n)$ bounds.) Obviously, since its $\Theta$-runtime is $\Theta(n \log n)$.